# get new records from table based on other one record in table

Tags: fetch, multiple-records

```
SELECT group_no,group_name, dept_no, dept_name, brand, from_nnm,to_nnm 
  FROM xx_nnm_benchmark
```

I have one record from the above query for group_no 1100 and dept_no 50
I have one more deps table in which i have 8 more deptno from group_no 1100
I need to get 8more records with same group_no,name

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to join both these table on unique id. we can assume your 'group_no and group_name' together as unique and do inner join. left or right join might also work but i would go for inner for this task

```
SELECT a.group_no,
a.group_name,
a.dept_no as adepno,
a.dept_name as adepname,
b.dept_no,
b.dept_name,
a.brand,
a.from_nnm,
a.to_nnm
FROM xx_nnm_benchmark a inner join deps b
on (a.group_no = b.group_no and a.group_name = b.group_name)
```

Comment: we dont have the group_name column in dept table. 
 For example in table one i have record for dept50 , then i need to get 8 more records from deps table  say 60,70,80,90.....  for the same group_no,name,but different dept_no & dept_name with brand,from_nnm,to_nnm as blank for 8 new records

Comment: you can just join on using group_no.

Comment: I have edited my answer. bascially you can add column names from any joining table. if they have the same column names then you have rename it for one.

Comment: No mkpisk it doesnot works its only fetching one record from table1, not for all the dept_no for the deps table

Comment: is your dept_no character variable or numeric?

Comment: dept_no is numeric, group_no is numeric

Comment: can you show share few samples of data from both tables, including column names

Comment: select * from xx_nnm_benchmark
group_no  grp_name              deptno    deptname        brand      from   to
1100         DIGITAL IMAGING    40          CAMERA       NIKON    5        10

select dept,group_no from deps where group_no=1100
dept  grpno
40    1100
50    1100
60    1100
180    1100
490    1100
1708    1100
3500    1100
4015    1100
4310    1100